# How to keep a fixed size of unique values in random positions in an array while replacing others with a mask?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, random, numpy-ndarray

This can be a very simple question as I am still exploring Python. And for this issue I use numpy.
**Updated 09/30/21:** adopted and modified codes shown below for any potential future reference. I also added an elif in the loop for classes that have fewer counts than the wanted size. Some codes may be unnecessary tho.

```
new_array = test_array.copy()
uniques, counts = np.unique(new_array, return_counts=True)
print("classes:", uniques, "counts:", counts)
for unique, count in zip(uniques, counts):
    #print (unique, count)
    if unique != 0 and count > 3:
        ids = np.random.choice(count, count-3, replace=False)
        new_array[tuple(i[ids] for i in np.where(new_array == unique))] = 0
    elif unique != 0 and count <= 3:
        ids = np.random.choice(count, count, replace=False)
        new_array[tuple(i[ids] for i in np.where(new_array == unique))] = unique
```

**Below is original question.**

Let's say I have a 2D array like this:

```
test_array = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],
                      [1,1,1,1,1],
                      [0,0,0,0,0],
                      [2,2,2,4,4],
                      [4,4,4,2,2],
                      [0,0,0,0,0]])
print("existing classes:", np.unique(test_array))
# "existing classes: [0 1 2 4]"
```

Now I want to keep **a fixed size** (e.g. 2 values) in each class that != 0 (in this case two 1s, two 2s, and two 4s) and replace the rest with 0. Where the value **being replaced is random** with each run (or from a seed).

For example, with run 1 I will have

```
([[0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0],
[2,0,0,0,4],
[4,0,0,2,0],
[0,0,0,0,0]])
```

with another run it might be

```
([[0,0,0,0,0],
[1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0],
[2,0,2,0,4],
[4,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0]])
```

etc. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My strategy is

1. Create a new array initialized to all zeros
2. Find the elements in each class
3. For each class

   - Randomly sample two of elements to keep
   - Set those elements of the new array to the class value

The trick is keeping the shape of the indexes appropriate so you retain the shape of the original array.

```py
import numpy as  np
test_array = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],
                      [1,1,1,1,1],
                      [0,0,0,0,0],
                      [2,2,2,4,4],
                      [4,4,4,2,2],
                      [0,0,0,0,0]])

def sample_classes(arr, n_keep=2, random_state=42):
    classes, counts = np.unique(test_array, return_counts=True)
    rng = np.random.default_rng(random_state)
    out = np.zeros_like(arr)
    for klass, count in zip(classes, counts):
        # Find locations of the class elements
        indexes = np.nonzero(arr == klass)
        # Sample up to n_keep elements of the class
        keep_idx = rng.choice(count, n_keep, replace=False)
        # Select the kept elements and reformat for indexing the output array and retaining its shape
        keep_idx_reshape = tuple(ind[keep_idx] for ind in indexes)
        out[keep_idx_reshape] = klass
    return out
```

You can use it like

```
In [3]: sample_classes(test_array)                                                                                                                                                                         [3/1174]
Out[3]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 4, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [4]: sample_classes(test_array, n_keep=3)
Out[4]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 4, 0],
       [4, 4, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [5]: sample_classes(test_array, random_state=88)
Out[5]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 4, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [6]: sample_classes(test_array, random_state=88, n_keep=4)
Out[6]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 4, 4],
       [4, 4, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my not-so-elegant solution:

```py
def unique(arr, num=2, seed=None):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    vals = {}
    for i, row in enumerate(arr):
        for j, val in enumerate(row):
            if val in vals and val != 0:
                vals[val].append((i, j))
            elif val != 0:
                vals[val] = [(i, j)]
    new = np.zeros_like(arr)
    for val in vals:
        np.random.shuffle(vals[val])
        while len(vals[val]) > num:
            vals[val].pop()
        for row, col in vals[val]:
            new[row,col] = val
    return new
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should be O(n log n) in array size

```
def keep_k_per_class(data,k,rng):
    out = np.zeros_like(data)
    unq,cnts = np.unique(data,return_counts=True)
    assert (cnts >= k).all()
    # calculate class boundaries from class sizes
    CNTS = cnts.cumsum()
    # indirectly group classes together by partial sorting
    idx = data.ravel().argpartition(CNTS[:-1])
    # the following lines implement simultaneous drawing without replacement
    # from all classes

    # lower boundaries of intervals to draw random numbers from
    # for each class they start with the lower class boundary 
    # and from there grow one by one - together with the
    # swapping out below this implements "without replacement"
    lb = np.add.outer(np.arange(k),CNTS-cnts)
    pick = rng.integers(lb,CNTS,lb.shape)
    for l,p in zip(lb,pick):
        # populate output array
        out.ravel()[idx[p]] = unq
        # swap out used indices so still available ones occupy a linear
        # range (per class)
        idx[p] = idx[l]
    return out
```

Examples:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
>>> 
>>> keep_k_per_class(test_array,2,rng)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 2, 0, 4],
       [0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> keep_k_per_class(test_array,2,rng)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 4, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

and a large one

```
>>> BIG = np.add.outer(np.tile(test_array,(100,100)),np.arange(0,500,5))
>>> BIG.size
30000000
>>> res = keep_k_per_class(BIG,30,rng)
### takes ~4 sec

### check
>>> np.unique(np.bincount(res.ravel()),return_counts=True)
(array([       0,       30, 29988030]), array([100, 399,   1]))
```